# SQL query join not working

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables.`tooth,toothchart and tblpatient` 
following are  `column` names

```
tooth-Tid,toothName
toothchart-patientId,stage, TeethCode,note
tblpatient-patientId,fname
```

I want to get all the values from '`tooth`' table and '`teethchart`' table for a given patient values from '`tblpatient`' table,but my query doesn't give all the values of `tooth` table.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT tooth.*,teethchart.*,fname 
FROM tooth 
LEFT JOIN teethchart ON tooth.toothName = teethchart.TeethCode 
left join tblpatient on teethchart.patientId=tblpatient.patientId 
where teethchart.patientId = 'P0001'
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will pull all the items from the tooth chart, and only those matching from teethchart and tblpatient

```
SELECT t.*, p.fname, tc.*
From tooth t
left join teethchart tc on t.toothName = tc.TeethCode
left join tblpatient p on tc.patientId = p.patientId
and p.patientId = 'P0001';
```